# How can i take a value from two inputs,and write in innerHTML in page?

Tags: javascript, html, math

```
 var a, b, result;
function setValues(){
     a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
     b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
}
function addition(){
   setValues();
   result.innerHTML = a + b;


}
```

How to take a two values from both input forms,and display the result in innerHTML? 
Its not working in my code. Thank you for help.

Comment: You have declared the `result` variable but you haven't assigned a element to it so your `.innerHTML` will not work.

Comment: I think to create a innerHTML just to get values from the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues with your code.

You are not calling the addition function.

You then need to specify the html element where you want to put the value of adding the two values.

```js
var a, b, result;

function setValues() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
}


function addition() {
  setValues();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a + b;
};

addition();
```

```html
<input id="num1" value=4>

<input id="num2" value=4>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add event listeners to each input element, and when the listener invokes the callback, return the result of `setValues` to the `innerText` property of the element (`innerHTML` works, but is intended to change HTML and not only text).

```js
/** get a reference to all elements involved, and cache the reference **/
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");

function setValues(){
     var a = Number(num1.value);
     var b = Number(num2.value);
     return a + b; // return a result from the function
}

function addition(){
   result.innerText = setValues(); // set the result as the text of the p element
}

/** add and event listener to each input **/
num1.addEventListener('input', addition);
num2.addEventListener('input', addition);
```

```html
<input id="num1" type="number"> <!-- set type number -->

<input id="num2" type="number"> <!-- set type number -->

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `div` whose `innerHTML` will be changed. Add a div to your page, then select it and then use change that using js innerHTML. If you are using a function that needs to be called so call the function on any event ex. click.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. Global variable is not needed unless its used in multiple places.

```
function getValues(){
     var a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
     var b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
     return a + b;
}
function addition(){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getValues();
}
addition();
```

HTML code

```
<input id="num1" value="1">
<input id="num2" value="2">
<input id="result" value="">
```